# How can I fix transmission's bizzare layout?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gui, interface, transmission

A couple of weeks ago I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 and I opened yesterday transmission for the first time and noticed that the layout is not what like I remembered it. As you can see

[image: here]

the 'show' toolbar is far larger than all other elements inside the window. How can I fix it and turn it to a normal sized toolbar?

Comment: You've themed your system. Choose the standard theme and see if Transmission is any better.

Comment: @heynnema thank you! The icon pack was messing with the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinstall it:

```
sudo apt purge transmission 
sudo apt update
sudo apt install transmission
```

Maybe an issue happened during this package upgrading.

Also, if it will not solve the issue try to change theme or even try to launch it in different desktop environment to see if issue somehow related to that.